# How to tell if a file is gzip compressed?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I have a Python program which is going to take text files as input.  However, some of these files may be gzip compressed.

Is there a cross-platform, usable from Python way to determine if a file is gzip compressed or not?

Is the following reliable or could an ordinary text file 'accidentally' look gzip-like enough for me to get false positives?

```
try:
    gzip.GzipFile(filename, 'r')
    # compressed
    # ...
except:
    # not compressed
    # ...
```

Comment: Just a small hint... never rely on the file ending. See hop's answer for how to do it.

Comment: @Helper: i'm not sure (see my edit). you'd still have to deal with a possible IOError, but gzipped files without the suffix are broken, in my opinion… tough call :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [magic number](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic-number.html) for gzip compressed files is `1f 8b`. Although testing for this is not 100% reliable, it is highly unlikely that "ordinary text files" start with those two bytes—in UTF-8 it's not even legal.

Usually gzip compressed files sport the suffix `.gz` though. Even `gzip(1)` itself won't unpack files without it unless you `--force` it to. You could conceivably use that, but you'd still have to deal with a possible IOError (which you have to in any case).

One problem with your approach is, that `gzip.GzipFile()` will not throw an exception if you feed it an uncompressed file. Only a later `read()` will. This means, that you would probably have to implement some of your program logic twice. Ugly.

Comment: gzip compressed files often have the .gz file extension (in fact, I don't think I've ever seen a .gzip extension), but it's generally unsafe to rely on file extension to test for the type of file anyhow.

Comment: Does it? - The gzip C library will transparently read uncompressed files. Although it will write files uncompressed it puts CRC codes through them to allow "gzip -t" (caught me out once)

Comment: @Martin: it does: $ gunzip foo
gzip: foo: unknown suffix -- ignored

Comment: The c 'library' gzip, ie gzopen/gzread/etc will transparently read uncompressed files. They have an open compression=none mode which does NOT write unchanged flat files.

Comment: About extensions. You would also have to check for the relatively common `.tgz` extension.

Answer (score 47):

> Is there a cross-platform, usable from Python way to determine if a file is gzip compressed or not?

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703300/1983854) explains how one can detect a gzip compressed file in general: **test if the first two bytes are `1f 8b`**. However it does not show how to implement it in Python.

Here is one way:

```
def is_gz_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as test_f:
        return test_f.read(2) == b'\x1f\x8b'
```

Comment: Can be done without binascii as well: `test_f.read(2) == b'\x1f\x8b'`

Comment: For a lower false positive rate, you can test that the first _three_ bytes are `1f 8b 08`.

Comment: If the file is not a `.gz` file, doesn't `test_f.read(2)` throw `OSError` in the first place? Is there still a need to check the bytes using `test_f.read(2) == b'\x1f\x8b'`? EDIT: it seems that this is only available since python 3.7.

Answer (score 15):

Testing the [magic number](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic-number.html) of a gzip file is the only reliable way to go. However, as of python3.7 there is no need to mess with comparing bytes yourself anymore. The gzip module will compare the bytes for you and raise an exception if they do not match!

As of python3.7, this works

```py
import gzip
with gzip.open(input_file, 'r') as fh:
    try:
        fh.read(1)
    except OSError:
        print('input_file is not a valid gzip file by OSError')
```

As of python3.8, this also works:

```py
import gzip
with gzip.open(input_file, 'r') as fh:
    try:
        fh.read(1)
    except gzip.BadGzipFile:
        print('input_file is not a valid gzip file by BadGzipFile')
```

Comment: The `OSError` exception can be raised even for valid `gzip` compressed files. You might not have permission to read that file, your OS might run out of memory while reading it, etc. Here `LBYL` wins over `EAFP`.

Comment: Is that the case for the `BadGzipFile` error as well? Also, wouldn't an error for bad permissions  and etc. be raised while opening the file?

Comment: The exception `BadGzipFile` is indeed raised only for bad gzip files. Note also, that testing magic number gives you the answer "this is not a gzip file", catching the exception `BadGzipFile` gives you the answer "this is not a _good_ gzip file". Thus both serve a slightly different purpose.

Comment: Also, you're right, your code is affected only by reading-related `OSError` exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` itself will raise an `OSError` if it's not a gzipped file.

```
>>> with gzip.open('README.md', 'rb') as f:
...     f.read()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/dennis/.asdf/installs/python/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Users/dennis/.asdf/installs/python/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 463, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/Users/dennis/.asdf/installs/python/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 411, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'# ')
```

Can combine this approach with some others to increase confidence, such as checking the mimetype or looking for a magic number in the file header (see other answers for an example) and checking the extension.

```
import pathlib

if '.gz' in pathlib.Path(filepath).suffixes:
   # some more inexpensive checks until confident we can attempt to decompress
   # ...
   try ...
     ...
   except OSError as e:
     ...
```

Comment: python 3.8 now adds a more specific error called `gzip.BadGzipFile` for this purpose. This error still inherits from `OSError`.

Answer (score 0):

Import the [mimetypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) module.
It can automatically guess what kind of file you have, and if it is compressed.

i.e.

```
mimetypes.guess_type('blabla.txt.gz')
```

returns:

('text/plain', 'gzip')

Comment: `mimetypes` only checks the end of the filename, it doesn't actually guess based on the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t seem to work well in python3...

```
import mimetypes
filename = "./datasets/test"

def file_type(filename):
    type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    return type
print(file_type(filename))
```

returns (None, None)
But from the unix command "File"

:~> file datasets/test 
datasets/test: gzip compressed data, was "iostat_collection", from Unix, last modified: Thu Jan 29 07:09:34 2015

Comment: mimetypes uses juts the filename to guess the type. To detect a filetype from the raw file you will need to use the 'magic' module.