# Change python byte type to string

Tags: python, urllib

I'm using python to play with the stackoverflow API.  I run the following commands:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats')
d = f.read()
```

The type of d is class 'bytes' and if I print it it looks like:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00 .... etc
```

I tried `d=f.read().decode('utf-8')` as that is the charset indicated in the header, but I get a 
  `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1"` error message

How do I convert the byte object I received from my urllib.request call to a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure your response body is not gzipped.  Believe its transfer encoding or such for the response header,  i have a high confidence that your dealing with compressed data and not character set encoding issues.

update:  Realizing I have a bad habit of not explaining/providing enough detail.  For Python gzip'd byte strings they always start with 1f8b  Someone explains it better here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703300/9908

Comment: you got it. I solved it with the following:
import zlib
decompressed_data=zlib.decompress(f.read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)