# Python3 urlopen read weirdness (gzip)

Tags: python-3.x, urlopen

I'm getting an URL from Schema.org. It's content-type="text/html"

Sometimes, read() functions as expected b'< !DOCTYPE html> ....'

Sometimes, read() returns something else b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00 ...'

```
try:
    with urlopen("http://schema.org/docs/releases.html") as f:
        txt = f.read()
except URLError:
    return
```

I've tried solving this with `txt = f.read().decode("utf-8").encode()` but this results in an error... sometimes: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

The obvious work-around is to test if the first byte is hex and treat this accordingly.

My question is: Is this a bug or something else?

[image]
**Edit**
Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746993/change-python-byte-type-to-string). Apparently, sometimes I'm getting a gzipped stream.

**Lastly**
I solved this by adding the following code as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695152/in-python-how-do-i-decode-gzip-encoding)

```
if 31 == txt[0]:
    txt = decompress(txt, 16+MAX_WBITS)
```

The question remains; why does this return text/html sometimes and zipped some other times?

Comment: I can only reproduce the case where you receive b'<!DOCTYPE ...
Seems to me like the other response you receive has something to do with your internet connection failing one way or another.

Comment: @SlashV I get this maybe once every 5 times

Comment: I ran the code 200 times...

Comment: @SlashV I'm using PyCharm, I dunno

Comment: @SlashV Added screenshot

Comment: I see your edit now. When you receive a zipped stream, you'll obviously have to unzip it first. You can probably avoid getting a zipped response by adding an "Accept" header.

Comment: @SlashV Cool, I'll do that. I've seen a number of questions related to zipped streams on StackOverflow. Should I delete this Q?

Comment: @SlashV Shouldn't that rather be [`Accept-Encoding`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-102)?

Comment: @dhke yup. In particular I feel that  `Accept-Encoding: identity` should help

Comment: @SlashV Yeah. `urlopen()` doesn't specify `Accept-Encoding` at all, which the server previously [MAY](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.3) interpret as `Accept-Encoding: *`. This has changed with [RFC7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.4). From the question history, I'd really consider this a wiki-answer case.

Comment: I cannot not get gzipped data from this url **even if** I specify `Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1` or `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`, so it seems to me this server has some rules of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other questions in this category, but I cannot find an answer that addresses the actual cause of the problem.

Python's `urllib2.urlopen()` cannot transparently handle compression. It also by default does not set the `Accept-Encoding` request header. Additionally, the interpretation of this situation according to the HTTP standard has changed in the past.

As per [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.3):

> If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, the server **MAY
> assume that the client will accept any content coding**. In this case,
> if "identity" is one of the available content-codings, then the
> server **SHOULD use the "identity" content-coding**, unless it has
> additional information that a different content-coding is meaningful
> to the client.

Unfortunately (as for the use case), [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4) changes this to

> If no Accept-Encoding field is in the request, **any content-coding is considered acceptable by the user agent**.

Meaning, when performing a request using `urlopen()` you can get a response  in whatever encoding the server decides to use and the response will be conformant.

*schema.org* seems to be hosted by google, i.e. it is most likely behind a distributed frontend load balancer network. So the different answers you get might be returned from load balancers with slightly different configurations.

Google Engineers have in the past [advocated for the use HTTP compression](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer?hl=en), so this might as well be a conscious decision.

So as a lesson: when using `urlopen()` we need to set `Accept-Encoding`.

Comment: I suspected something like that. A load balancer seems the reasonable explanation. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed receiving a gzipped response. You should be able to avoid it by:

```
from urllib import request
try:
    req = request.Request("http://schema.org/docs/releases.html")
    req.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'identity;q=1')
    with request.urlopen(req) as f:
        txt = f.read()
except request.URLError:
    return
```

Comment: The work-around I've chosen is to decompress it... less code

Comment: @GUIJunkie nah, both are two lines **and** you'll have to do an extra import for the `decompress` ;)

Comment: :-) I also had to do an extra import for the Request. Shrugs.