# SeqIO.parse on a fasta.gz

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, gzip

New to coding.  New to Pytho/biopython; this is my first question online, ever.
How do I open a compressed fasta.gz file to extract info and perform calcuations in my function.  Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do (I've tried different ways), and what the error is. The gzip command I'm using doesn't seem to work.?

```
with gzip.open("practicezip.fasta.gz", "r") as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
        print(record.id)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-192-a94ad3309a16>", line 2, in <module>
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\__init__.py", line 600, in parse
    for r in i:

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\FastaIO.py", line 122, in FastaIterator
    for title, sequence in SimpleFastaParser(handle):

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\FastaIO.py", line 46, in SimpleFastaParser
    if line[0] == ">":

IndexError: index out of range
```

Comment: I've had similar errors to this one when I've accidentally parsed a fastq file using the wrong format. If you unzip the fasta file and briefly inspect it with a text editor, you don't see anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Are you using python3?

This ("r" --> "rt") could solve your problem.

```
import gzip
from Bio import SeqIO

with gzip.open("practicezip.fasta.gz", "rt") as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
        print(record.id)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution if you want to handle both regular text and gzipped files:

```
import gzip
from mimetypes import guess_type
from functools import partial
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = 'input_file.fa.gz'

encoding = guess_type(input_file)[1]  # uses file extension
_open = partial(gzip.open, mode='rt') if encoding == 'gzip' else open

with _open(input_file) as f:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f, 'fasta'):
        print(record)
```

Note: this relies on the file having the correct file extension, which I think is reasonable nearly all of the time (and the errors are obvious and explicit if this assumption is not met). However, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703276/how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-gzip-compressed) for ways to actually check the file content rather than relying on this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

@klim's answer is good.
However, in some cases you dont want to iterate but just select a single entry. In such cases, use following code:

```
import pyfastx
fa = pyfastx.Fasta('ATEST.fasta.gz')
s1 = fa['KF530110.1']
fa_sequence = s1.seq
```

It creates an additional file, namely it indexes each fasta entry. It's really fast.