# I need to improve a function that parses a multi fasta file, checking for compression with a try execpt handling

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

Hi guys I am working with a huge gz compressed fasta file, and I have a nice fasta parser but I would like to make it more general, in the way I can check for compression, to parse a gz or a not compressed file.

I try this code:

```
def is_header(line):
    return line[0] == '>'

def parse_multi_fasta_file_compressed_or_not(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        with gzip.open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            fasta_iter = (it[1] for it in itertools.groupby(f, is_header))
    else:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            fasta_iter = (it[1] for it in itertools.groupby(f, is_header))
            for name in fasta_iter:
                name = name.__next__()[1:].strip()
                sequences = ''.join(seq.strip() for seq in fasta_iter.__next__())
                yield name, sequences
```

ref:
https://drj11.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/python-getting-fasta-with-itertools-groupby/
https://www.biostars.org/p/710/

I tried to modify the identation. Python doesn't complain about any error. However, it doesn't print or show any results. I am using a toy file with 5 sequences.

Just to remind a fasta file is something like that:

```
>header_1
AATATATTCAATATGGAGAGAATAAAAGAACTAAGAGATCTAATGTCACAGTCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC
TCACCAAAACCACTGTGGACCACATGGCCATAATCAAAAAGTACACATCAGGAAGGCAAGAGAAGAACCC
TGCACTCAGGATGAAGTGGATGATG
>header_2
AACCATTTGAATGGATGTCAATCCGACTTTACTTTTCTTGAAAGTTCCAGCGCAAAATGCCATAAGCACC
ACATTTCCCTATACTGGAGACCCTCC
```

I would like to use some `try:... except:...` instead of `if`.
If any of you have any tip to help me figure that out, I would appreciate it a lot (it's not any course exercice at all!).

Thank you for your time.

Paulo

Comment: I wrote a general solution using biopython https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839332/6260170

Comment: That is nice to Chris. Thank you for your time and attention. :)

Comment: I tend to use `fastx_read` from the mappy package: it parses fastq and fasta, gzipped or not, transparently. See https://github.com/lh3/minimap2/blob/master/python/README.rst#miscellaneous-functions

Comment: I will check it out bli, thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have overly indented your `for loop. Try the following:

```
def is_header(line):
    return line[0] == '>'

def parse_multi_fasta_file_compressed_or_not(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        opener = lambda filename: gzip.open(filename, 'rt')
    else:
        opener = lambda filename: open(filename, 'r')

    with opener(filename) as f:
        fasta_iter = (it[1] for it in itertools.groupby(f, is_header))
        for name in fasta_iter:
            name = name.__next__()[1:].strip()
            sequences = ''.join(seq.strip() for seq in fasta_iter.__next__())
            yield name, sequences
```

I've also rearranged things a little so you can use the `with` block as you did before. The conditional at the beginning assigns to `opener` a function which can open the given file depending on whether it is gzipped or not.

Comment: Hi Michael thank you for your time and attention. I will check it out.  8)