# handling gzip.open or open in with statement

Tags: python

Reading in a batch of syslog files. Some of them have been compressed:

```
syslog
syslog.1
syslog.2.gz
syslog.3.gz
syslog.4.gz
```

```
with open(args.filename_path, "rb") as file:
```

Everything seems to work ok when using gzip.open in the `with` statement when the extension is `gz`:

```
with gzip.open(args.filename_path, "rb") as file:
```

How to get the `gzip.open` when it's a `gz` file but use `open` when it's a "normal" file.

Comment: Do you iterate and check the file endings to use either `with open(file)` or `with gz.open(file)`?

Comment: I'm confused. You say everything works using gzip.open then ask how to get gzip.open to work with a gz file. Is the question how to know when to use open verses gzip.open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [hook_compressed()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.hook_compressed) of the standard module `fileinput` that does exactly what you are asking for:

> Transparently opens files compressed with **gzip** and **bzip2** (recognized by the extensions *.gz* and *.bz2*) using the `gzip` and `bz2` modules. If the filename extension is not *.gz* or *.bz2*, the file is opened normally (ie, using `open()` without any decompression).

```py
with fileinput.hook_compressed("test.txt.gz") as f:
   f.read()
with fileinput.hook_compressed("test.txt") as f:
    f.read()
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is check if the file is gzipped and if it is, use `gzip.open`, otherwise use `open`.

```py
import gzip

paths = ["foo.log", "bar.log.gz"]

def is_gzipped(path):
    return path.endswith(".gz")

for path in paths:
    open_fn = gzip.open if is_gzipped(path) else open
    with open_fn(path) as f:
        pass  # do things with file
```

A better way to check if a file is gzipped is to query the "magic numbers" and see if they match those of gzip. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080739/5666087 for more information.

```py
def is_gzipped(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return f.read(2) == b'\x1f\x8b'
```

Comment: It may also be better to have `is_gzipped` attempt `gzip.open` on the file and catch the exception. Then you are not extension dependent.

Comment: @tdelaney - good idea. what do you think about checking the magic numbers?

Comment: That's worked nicely thank you @tdelaney. Apologies, reading it back I wasn't absolutely clear in my original description, my problem was to make `with` happen with `gzip.open` when the file is compressed.

Comment: I like the "magic" number suggestion also and will work that into my script too.

Comment: @jakob I like the magic number test especially if you want to expand the number of compressors supported. Magic number isn't fool proof. You'll still want to wrap the gzip open in an exception handler just in case. And since you are doing that anyway, why bother with the magic number.

Comment: @tdelaney - interestingly, i was exploring the gzip module and it raises an exception if the magic numbers are not correct. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/00726e51ade10c7e3535811eb700418725244230/Lib/gzip.py#L434-L435

Answer (score 1):

It should work well.
Here is an example for you:

In the OS:

```
cat test.txt
foo
bar

gzip test.txt
```

Even if the extension is not `gz`:

In the OS:

```
mv test.txt.gz test.txt
```

In Python:
with gzip.open("test.txt") as f:
print(f.read())

```
foo
bar
```

In Python:

```
with gzip.open("test.txt.gz") as f:
     print(f.read())
    
foo
bar
```

However, if the file is not `gzip` compressed, then you will get an exception `IOError: Not a gzipped file`.

Comment: Then that's the problem, isn't it?

Comment: @tripleee It is not clear what the problem is, because the question was: "How to get the gzip.open when it's a gz file?"

Comment: I agree that the OP should probably clarify.